# 'Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7' error when deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I have a Java server on Google App Engine. Recently I have been unable to deploy online due to this error:

```
 IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7
```

Can anyone advise? I have already tried the following based on other reports:

- Setting `web.xml` version to 2.5
- Setting Eclipse JRE to Java 7 (in Run Configurations > JRE > Execution Environment: JavaSE-1.7)
- Adding the following to `pom.xml`:

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `java compiler compliance level` by following steps below.

1) go to `Project property`.

2) click `Java Compiler` view in Properties view.

3) check enable project specific setting then select your compiler compliance level(jdk7 or jdk8) which you want.

[image]